# Regarding the question of implementing a native Windows title bar using Lua script

Tags: lua, windows-11

When using GUI software in my daily life, I found that as long as the Windows built-in decorative title bar is cancelled, no matter how good the title bar subsequently drawn by the software is, it cannot perfectly support the functions of Windows 11.

For example, when I move the mouse to the maximize button in the upper right corner of the window, which triggers drag and drop-like functionality as shown in Figure 1, it cannot be implemented as shown in Figure 2, if I choose to hide the default title bar.

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

Cancelling the title bar also prevents software from being dragged, such as the MPV-player win version. So, is this an oversight by the programmer, or is the feature difficult to implement?

If I want to use Lua to implement a custom title bar that restores the native Windows title bar for MPV but with additional features such as transparency, how can I solve this problem? Where should I start with this idea?